# Comparing Array Values With Object Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-in-loop

Write a function called "select".

Given an array and an object, "select" returns a new object whose properties are those in the given object AND whose keys are present in the given array.

```
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};
var output = select(arr, obj);
console.log(output); // --> { a: 1, c: 3 }
```

My Solution:

```
function select(arr, obj) {
  for (var k in obj) {
    return arr.reduce((o, c) => {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
        o[c] = obj[c]
      }
      return o
    }, {})
  }
}

var array = ['a', 'c', 'e'];

var object = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};

console.log(select(array, object));
```

My solution is working, but I have a feeling that I'm not using the best practices or most eloquent code. For example I'm using a for/in to search the object, but I never use the 'k' from for (var k in obj). Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, just omit the `for (var k in obj) {`. It has absolutely no purpose in your code. Can you explain what you meant it to do?

Comment: I wanted to search over every property of the object @Bergi

Comment: @jhazelton1 you don't need to iterate over `obj` as you're using `arr.reduce` to do that.

Comment: And you are returning on the first iteration, so there won't be a lookup over all properties of the object either way

Answer (score 1):

To get the intersection between the keys of the objects and the keys in the array, there are two approaches:

- enumerate the object property keys and check which of them are also in the array
- iterate the keys in the array and check which of them are also an object property

**You don't have to do both loops.** The first approach will be more efficient for small objects, the second one works well for large objects and small subsets as well.

```
function select(arr, obj) {
  let o = {};
  for (let k in obj)
    if (arr.includes(k))
      o[k] = obj[k];
  return o;
}

function select(arr, obj) {
  let o = {};
  for (let k of arr)
    if (k in obj)
      o[k] = obj[k];
  return o;
}
```

You can also use `reduce` instead of the `for … of` loop like you successfully did (I won't repeat that solution), but which of the two is easier to read and understand only you can decide.

Comment: I think you are missing a curly brace.

Comment: @LaravelSucks Rather, having one too much :-) Thanks, fixed!

Comment: This only matches the first key and then it returns.

Comment: @London804 No it doesn't? The `return` statements are *after* the respective loop

Comment: @Bergi I'm sorry you're right. It looks like my console.log was in the loop. I will upvote as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign()` with `reduce()` and inside check if property exists in object.

```js
var arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
var obj = { a: 1,b: 2,c: 3, d: 4};

let select = (arr, obj) => arr.reduce((r, e) => Object.assign(r, obj[e] ? {[e]: obj[e]} : null), {})

var output = select(arr, obj);
console.log(output); // --> { a: 1, c: 3 }
```

Comment: Don't pass a string to `Object.assign`. Pass `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array with Array#reduce and pluck all properties that exist on the object to a new object:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'c', 'e'];
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};

const select = (arr, obj) => arr.reduce((r, prop) => {
    obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && (r[prop] = obj[prop]);
    
    return r;
  }, {});

const output = select(arr, obj);
console.log(output); // --> { a: 1, c: 3 }
```